# Windows batch script: saving a list of selected file to new text file using ECHO

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, explorer

I have provided all the detail and code below, but, the problem is only in the last line.

Background

I am creating a script named, GetSelectedFiles.cmd, whose shortcut is added to Windows' "Send To" context menu. For example, by copying the shortcut of above file to location: `c:\users\user\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo`.

Purpose:

The goal of that script file is to get the list of selected file names when the user goes to the context menu and selects Send To > GetSelectedFiles.cmd.

Requirement:

```
1) The the selected file names will be separated by new lines.
2) The list will only contain the bare file name and extension (no path).
3) The list will be a saved inside the same directory as selected files.
4) The list will will be saved in a file whose file name matches the first selected file and has extension of `.selection`.
```

Example:

Assume you are in directory `c:\users\u\`. Say this directory has files named: w.txt, x.txt, y.txt, z.txt, with some other files.

User selects those above named 4 files, right clicks and does Send To > GetSelectedFiles.cmd.

After completing the above steps, the directory should have a new file named `w.selection` and it should contain following lines

```
w.txt
x.txt
y.txt
z.txt
```

It is a basic task, but, where I am having problem is the last line, specifically `%firstFile%` just returns empty. What am I missing?

```
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:::: Here is the complete code :::::
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

:: For new line const
set LF=^



for %%A in (%*) do (
IF NOT DEFINED firstFile  (SET firstFile=%%~nxA)

::: This last line is the problem!
echo %%~nxA ^%LF% >> %%~dpA%firstFile%.selection
)
```

Comment: you need [delayed expansion](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082)

Comment: ... or use `echo %%~nxA ^%LF% >> %%~dpnxA.selection` (instead of `%%~dpnxA` you can also use `%%~fA`)

Comment: @Stephan: It worked, Great! I just replaced %firstFile% on the the last line to !firstFile!